# How to express error function by confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function, error-function

I am struggling to express error function by confluent hypergeometric function

Which I found on wikipedia: $\displaystyle \operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac{2x}{\sqrt \pi} \Phi \left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-x^2\right)$

I tried to Taylor expand it then integrate it which results in $\displaystyle \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}$

From my book, this problem provided a hint $2n+1= \dfrac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}$, which this hints seems doesn't make any sense to me as the numerical value should be $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: One minor mistake I see: Upon integrating $e^{-x^2}$, one should have $x^{2n+1}$ not $x^{2n}$ for the $n$th term in the Taylor series.

Comment: Yes, thank you for you reminder, I had edited it.

Comment: One true statement which is related to your book's (seemingly spurious) hint is $\dfrac{(3/2)_{n}}{(1/2)_{n}}=2n+1$ where $(a)_n=a(a-1)\cdots(a-n+1)$ is the Pochammer symbol (falling factorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{erf}(z)%
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k z^{2k+1}}{k! (2k+1)}\\
&=\frac{2z}{\sqrt\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-z^2)^k}{k! (2k+1)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{k+1/2}%
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma(k+1/2)}{\Gamma(k+3/2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma(k+1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(3/2)}\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(k+3/2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1/2)_k}{(3/2)_k}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(3/2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1/2)_k}{(3/2)_k}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(1/2)}\\
&=\frac{(1/2)_k}{(3/2)_k}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Substituting into our Taylor series then gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{erf}(z)%
&=\frac{2z}{\sqrt\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1/2)_k}{(3/2)_k}\frac{(-z^2)^k}{k!}\\
&=\frac{2z}{\sqrt\pi}{_1F_1}\left({1/2 \atop 3/2};-z^2\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
with the last equality being due to the definition of the generalized hypergeometric series.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very concise!